# On iOS, why would a dismiss view controller immediately followed by a present view controller not work?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit

The code that works used to be

```
[self presentViewController:aNewViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and `self` is the same class as `aNewViewController`, so it is a page that keeps on presenting a new page (with different data), by flipping horizontally.

But since `presentViewController` in this way can cause memory usage to be more and more (sort of like a web browser just having more and more history for Back and Forward), so I changed the code to:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO 
          completion:^{
              [self.presentingViewController 
                        presentViewController:aNewViewController
                        animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

But for some reason, it just "goes back" to the previous view controller's view, without going to the new one (`aNewViewController`).  Initially, I put the above code in 2 parallel lines, one after another, and then I put the second line in the completion block of the first call.  And these two methods both won't work as expected.  Is there something tricky that makes it not go to the new view controller?

Also, it used to have the good effect of flipping to the new content, but right now, if it works, it probably will flip back to the first page (the starting page), and then flip to the result page, and next time, flip to the starting page again.  Because the starting page looks quite different from the result page, I would rather it just keep on flipping showing the result page (from one result page, flip to another result page).  If I set the "dismiss" to have no animation, it won't have the flip animation, but it will still show the starting page first, and then flip to the result page.  Is there a way to solve this?

**Update:**  Won't it be true that `self` cease to exist after the dismiss? (the object is dealloc'ed).  The above code is actually done in a class method (the class is the same class of `aNewViewController`, which is the result page's view controller).  To solve the `self` issue, I tried to set a local variable first

```
UIViewController *presentingViewController = foo.presentingController;
[presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO 
          completion:^{
              [presentingViewController 
                        presentViewController:aNewViewController
                        animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

(`foo` is passed in, and have the value of `self`).  then it actually works!  But what if it is not a class method but is an instance method... will `self` not exist any more?  (If it is in an instance method, will the completion block keep the object alive?  But what about after the completion block, who is keeping the object alive?)  I did it in a class method because then the starting page can just call this class method to present this page (with URL data fetching logic).

Comment: I am surprised that this wont work since you are using the completion block. That worked for me in the past in slightly different scenarios.

Comment: oh by the way, isn't it true that when the dismiss is done, `self` cease to exist any more?  I am actually doing this in a class method, and passing `self` to this class method...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some delay between these two transitions. Try adding dealy of 0.40. Like `[self performSelector:@selector(anySelector:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.40];`

Comment: Why is that so, the dismiss action is 1. done without animation and 2. the following presenting is done within the completion block.

Comment: so if we need a 0.4 second delay, making it run in the next iteration of the main loop won't work?  yeah I wonder also why it needs such a big delay, 0.4 second is like 24 iterations of CADisplayLink already

Comment: @Rahul please see my second comment under the original question (and the update in the question)

Comment: Why you are using same viewcontroller ? you can do this on view itself. Like you can do a flip animation on self.view and change data in your viewController and update the view according to that. Current approach according to me is bad practice.

Comment: that's because what if the page can just from this data page to a "new members" page, or "hot topics" page, we would present view controller of the other page types, and when those pages need to jump to any data page, then present this view controller.